# Why are my SQLSRV queries not executing?

Tags: php, sql

Why are my SQLSRV queries not executing?

It doesn't echo anything like its supposed to on the IF ELSE failure does anyone see what my issue is? I can't figure out whats wrong, it looks like it should be working to me.

PHP Code:

```
/* IF NULL EXISTS of DATEIN or DATEOUT then UPDATE else INSERT*/
$datein_s="SELECT TOP 1 datein FROM clocked WHERE datein IS NULL AND userid=? ORDER BY datein DESC";
$datein_sr=sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$datein_s,$params);
$datein=sqlsrv_fetch($datein_sr);
$datein_q1="UPDATE clocked SET datein=GETDATE() WHERE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 datein FROM clocked WHERE datein IS NULL AND userid=? ORDER BY datein DESC);";
$datein_qr1=sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$datein_q1,$params);
$datein_q2="INSERT INTO clocked(datein) VALUES(GETDATE(),?);";
$datein_qr2=sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$datein_q2,$params);

$dateout_s="SELECT TOP 1 dateout FROM clocked WHERE dateout IS NULL AND userid=? ORDER BY dateout DESC";
$dateout_sr=sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$dateout_s,$params);
$dateout=sqlsrv_fetch($dateout_sr);
$dateout_q1="UPDATE clocked SET dateout=GETDATE() WHERE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 dateout FROM clocked WHERE dateout IS NULL AND userid=? ORDER BY dateout DESC);";
$dateout_qr1=sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$dateout_q1,$params);

if($datein===null)
{
$datein_qr1;
}
else if ($dateout===null)
{
$dateout_qr1;
}
else if ($datein===null&&$dateout===null)
{
$datein_qr1;
}
else if ($datein!==null&&$dateout!==null)
{
$datein_qr2;
}
else
{
echo "ERROR your query may be broken!";
}

/* END IF */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite follow the logic here, but I think the problem is that the lines at the top:

```
$datein_qr2=sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$datein_q2,$params);
```

are running the queries - I *think* what you're wanting to do is just initialise the queries at the top, and then run the appropriate one in the if statements, with:

```
$datein_qr1;
```

You'll need to move the sqlsrv_query line to inside the if statements.

Also, the third if statement won't ever be reached:

```
else if ($datein===null&&$dateout===null)
```

You're already checking to see if datein and dateout are null on the two previous if statements.

Comment: Can I ask what the issue was?

Comment: My insert query had an issue with its columns listed, when I fixed that and moved them it worked.

Answer (score 0):

strange code fragments :-)

you can try this

```
if($datein===null)
{
    $datein_q1="UPDATE clocked SET datein=GETDATE() WHERE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 datein FROM clocked WHERE datein IS NULL AND userid=? ORDER BY datein DESC);";
    sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$datein_q1,$params);
}
```

or with a closure (>= PHP 5.3)

```
$datein_q1="UPDATE clocked SET datein=GETDATE() WHERE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 datein FROM clocked WHERE datein IS NULL AND userid=? ORDER BY datein DESC);";
$caller= function($query, $params = array()) use($dbconnect) {
    sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$query,$params);
};

if($datein===null)
{
    $caller->__invoke($datein_q1, array();
}
```